# resize a volume

Tags: linux, lvm

I would like to increase lv_home to 20G and increase lv_root to 120G.
In VMware I extended the harddrive to 200G. You can see that below in .host:/

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                       48G   31G   15G  68% /
tmpfs                 3.1G  100K  3.1G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   81M  379M  18% /boot
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home
                      4.6G  198M  4.2G   5% /home
.host:/               239G  110G  130G  46% /mnt/hgfs
```

I tried to run

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home 20G
```

But it didn't work

I tried to run

```
lvextend -L 120G /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
```

But it didn't work

any ideas of how to add the space from .host over to lv_home?

Comment: The information provided is to partial to provide a proper answer.  Please post the resulting file from the command - executed as root "(pvs; vgs; lvs) > lvm-setup.lst"  - This command will give a summary of your LVS setup.  Also, what error message did you get from resize2fs ?  (Should it have been resize4fs ??)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see from your LVS command, your LVM partition is only 54.1 gigs, all of which is allocated.

Am I correct in understanding that this is actually a VM, and you expanded the size of the physical disk on the VM to 200 GIGS ?  If that is the case you need to first grow the PV, then the VG, then the LVs.   (PV=Physical Volume, VG=Volume Group, LV=Logical Volume)

I've not tried these commands (so back up, your data is at risk !!!), but
try the following -

1. Create a new partition with the free space (for example, use FDISK and
   create sda2 - if that does not work, please please show me the
   result of "fdisk -l /dev/sda")
2. Assuming the new partition is sda3 [ i'm guessing here, you might have
   a swap ] do the following
3. Create a new Physical Volume using sda3

```
pvcreate /dev/sda3
```

4. Add the new partition to your volume group

```
vgextend Volgroup /dev/sda3
```

5. Expand your partition

```
lvextend -L 120G /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
```

6. Resize the partition

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
```

Note that these commands are untested and will probably need a bit of tweeking.

Also, an alternative to the pvcreate and lvextend command would be to resize /dev/sda1 (if thats an option with Fdisk) and then grow the physical volume.

Comment: [root@mybox ~]# pvs; vgs; lvs
PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
      /dev/sda2  VolGroup lvm2 a--  54.51g    0 
      VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
      VolGroup   1   3   0 wz--n- 54.51g    0 
      LV      VG       Attr     LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Move Log      Copy%  Convert
      lv_home VolGroup -wi-ao--          4.67g                                           
      lv_root VolGroup -wi-ao--     47.87g                                           
      lv_swap VolGroup -wi-ao--      1.97g                                           
    [root@mybox ~]#

Comment: I ran the command pvs; vgs; lvs, but I dont know how to format it in the box.

Comment: +1 very useful. However be careful to case sensitivity, `Volgroup` not being the same as `VolGroup`.